# Are puberty blockers fully reversible?

Tags: medical-science, biology, gender, children

Multiple sources claim that puberty blockers function like a pause button. To name a few:

> Using puberty blockers is like hitting a pause button

[St. Louis Children's Hospital](https://www.stlouischildrens.org/conditions-treatments/transgender-center/puberty-blockers)

> “The really wonderful feature of puberty blockers is that they are a fully reversible medication,” Roberts says.

[MSN factcheck](https://www.msn.com/en-us/health/medical/five-myths-about-puberty-blockers-for-trans-kids-debunked/ar-AA12T4l0)

> it’s more like a pause. If we stop the medicine, puberty can restart,” says Dr. Cartaya. She adds that once it begins again, the body will go through puberty that’s associated with the sex assigned at birth.

[Cleveland Clinic](https://health.clevelandclinic.org/what-are-puberty-blockers/)

However [NHS](https://www.nationalreview.com/corner/puberty-blockers-not-so-reversible-after-all/) is no longer supporting prior positions, quoting [an article](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0243894)

> Newly published short-term outcomes research suggests that the effects of puberty blockers, specifically in relation to bone-mass density and height, are not as “fully reversible” as the clinic once promised.

**Are puberty blockers reversible***? 
**If so, to what degree**?

Edit 3.11.2022:
[mayoclinic.org](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/gender-dysphoria/in-depth/pubertal-blockers/art-20459075) claims

> Use of GnRH analogues might also have long-term effects on:
> Growth spurts
> Bone growth and density
> Future fertility — depending on when pubertal blockers are started

* To those who wish to quibble about meaning of reversible. I mean something to spirit of 'continue developing (and arriving to result) in the pathway, which would occur without the action/medication taken.' Are people put on blockers losing some biological function or do they suffer something that can't be reversed?

Answer (score 11):

The closest I've found to an indication that they are *not* reversible is the [NHS statement](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/gender-dysphoria/treatment/) that

> Little is known about the long-term side effects of hormone or puberty blockers in children with gender dysphoria.
>
> Although GIDS advises this is a physically reversible treatment if stopped, it is not known what the psychological effects may be.
>
> It's also not known whether hormone blockers affect the development of the teenage brain or children's bones. Side effects may also include hot flushes, fatigue and mood alterations.

So basically, they say that it does seem that the delayed puberty resumes normally, but there may be physical and mental side effects from the delay. Depending on your point of view, you could see that as reasonable caution, implying unsubstantiated danger, or weasel-wording just in case it turns out there are notable side effects in the future.

The specific study that you mention notes an increase in Bone Mineral Density and Bone Mineral Content at the 24 month mark, but not at the 36 month mark, which to me suggests that there is some difference when the blockers are present compared to their baseline figures, but that it went back to normal.

> 44 patients had data at 12 months follow-up, 24 at 24 months and 14 at 36 months. All had normal karyotype and endocrinology consistent with birth-registered sex. All achieved suppression of gonadotropins by 6 months. At the end of the study one ceased GnRHa and 43 (98%) elected to start cross-sex hormones.
>
> There was no change from baseline in spine BMD at 12 months nor in hip BMD at 24 and 36 months, but at 24 months lumbar spine BMC and BMD were higher than at baseline (BMC +6.0 (95% CI: 4.0, 7.9); BMD +0.05 (0.03, 0.07)). There were no changes from baseline to 12 or 24 months in CBCL or YSR total t-scores or for CBCL or YSR self-harm indices, nor for CBCL total t-score or self-harm index at 36 months. Most participants reported positive or a mixture of positive and negative life changes on GnRHa. Anticipated adverse events were common.

Of note to me, despite the study being cited as a reasoning for believing the changes are not reversible, it does not seem to show a lasting effect at the 36 month mark, and it does not study the actual effects of ceasing to use the puberty blockers, so the question of reversibility is not addressed.

Comment: Honestly, the major problem is that the sample size is small for clinical studies, and trying to survey the overall populace leads to anecdotal reporting problems. If you have a few dozen children who are on puberty blockers, and there's a difference in bone mass at 24 months, how do you know that you didn't just happen to get a batch of kids who had a different bone mass level? Will some people avoid reporting issues because they're afraid the treatment will be discontinued? And how often is data reinterpreted to fit a political or academic agenda?

Comment: Does that study say what the impact is of not doing them in the first place? From what I understand there are psychological impacts from not doing the treatment in the first place.

Comment: @JoeW I suspect the effects of natural puberty are well-known.

Comment: @MichaelW. I am not talking about the impact of puberty but the psychological impacts of not being able to undergo the treatment versus being able to. There are psychological  reasons that they want to do this in the first place and denying that treatment will have psychological impacts.

Comment: @JoeW the psychological impact depends on the person and why they may desire to delay puberty.  Sure gender dysphoria is a common reason, but it's not the only one. Even then degrees of gender dysphoria vary which in turn vary the severity of not delaying puberty.  Rather then trying to articulate all that complexity it seems completely reasonable to me to simply ask if there are negative affects to delaying puberty and then leave it up to an individual and their doctor(s) to determine if the anticipated advantage for them is worth any potential risk that was determined

Comment: @dsollen I understand that but that doesn't mean it should be ignored and not consider at all. I am simply asking if that was something that was considered or not.

Comment: Note that this is basically saying that it's not proven there are no lasting effects, not that there are lasting effects.

Comment: @JoeW While the psychological impact may be an interesting question, it's not the question that was asked.

Comment: @Kyralessa if you talk about the psychology impacts of taking them you should also talk about the psychological impacts of not taking them. I only asked the question because it talks about one side but not the other.

Comment: @JoeW: My apologies if you felt I didn't address your question. The study cited in the question does not discuss psychology at all. And the NIS statement does not cite a study for the question of psychological effects, positive or negative.

Comment: @JoeW No one talked about "the psychology [sic] impacts of taking them."  Read the answer again: "...it is not known what the psychological effects may be."  Should the answer be changed to say "...nor is it known what the psychological effects of not taking them may be"?  Perhaps the reader can infer that alone.

Comment: @Kyralessa The article that was quoted is talking about them and the impact that they can have on the brain. That is why I asked about the impact of not doing them can have.

Comment: @SeanDuggan I felt you addressed my question perfectly with the information that it wasn't addressed in the study at all. I was just responding to someone addressing my comment on your question.